# How to define Linux kernel driver SPI frame

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, spi

I'm working on a Linux kernel driver for the Texas Instruments [tps92518-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS92518-Q1) and [tps92518HV-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS92518HV-Q1). This device uses 16-bit SPI Frames (7-bit control, 9-bit data).

Command frame

```
1-bit command bit
5-bit Address
1-bit parity
9-bit data
```

Read response frame

```
1-bit SPI error
2-bit reserved
1-bit power cycle
1-bit LED2 BOOTUV ERROR
1-bit LED1 BOOTUV ERROR
1-bit THERMAL WARNING
9-bit data
```

Write response frame

```
1-bit SPI error
1-bit command
5-bit Address
9-bit data
```

The main problem here is the requirement for a parity bit on any write operation. So I need to be able to calculate the parity bit for any command frame

```c
PARITY = XNOR(CMD, A4..A0, D8..D0)
```

I can define a regmap, e.g.

```c
static struct regmap_config tps92518_regmap_config = {
   .reg_bits = 6,
   .pad_bits = 1, // parity bit
   .val_bits = 9,
   .max_register = tps92518_RESET,
};
```

From [regmap.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/regmap.h#L353) it looks like I might be able to set `->reg_read()` and `->reg_write()` callbacks, but I don't know what I would actually have get those functions to do.

Is there another method of preprocessing any request/response?

The Linux kernel [SPI documentation](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/spi.html#serial-peripheral-interface-spi) mentions the protocol drivers but can I see where I could specify a protocol format?

Comment: Do you have to write a linux kernel module for that? Why not write it in user-space? I do not think a kernel module is needed. I would believe that writing a kernel module is an overkill for that - use user-space SPI ioctl api. Anyway, if you _really_ want to write a kernel module for it, look at other kernel modules that interface with SPI - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/misc/ad714x.c https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/misc/adxl34x.c are I think the simplest.

Comment: `The main problem here is the requirement for a parity bit on any write operation` Just write a function that you pass `CMD, A4..A0, D8...D0` and the function creates the frame and calculates parity and then sends it. Build abstractions on top, why on the bottom.

Comment: @KamilCuk, why the user space? It's actually the right direction to create such module in the kernel space by a few reasons. I leave it for you to find which ones.

Comment: `why the user space?` Well, because it's easier to port and it's a hundred times easier to debug a segmentation fault vs a kernel panic.

Comment: @KamilCuk, so you are telling that running QEmu with in-kernel driver is different to run QEmu with user space code? Or are you suggesting to test on the development machine as is and reboot it?

Comment: If you can get the command frame as a 16-bit word, you can work out its parity with a function such as `u16 parity16(u16 v)` `{` `v ^= v >> 8;` `v ^= v >> 4;` `v ^= v >> 2;` `v ^= v >> 1;` return `v & 1;` `}`.